# Simple-todos app tutorial, trying to create a function that removes the checked tasks from Mongo collection

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, reactjs

I am stuck trying to create a new function in the simple-todos app.

This function is a button that removes all the selected tasks, like the checkbox that hides them, from the mongo collection. I have already created the button, which successfully calls the function I want. The only problem is that I can't make the function remove the tasks from the collection. I've tried creating arrays with all the tasks and sorting them out with an if/else, tried using the Collection.remove() and using the $ne to select only the checked ones (it gave the error 403, remove by ID only). Nothing worked.

So, I am creating this function into the ui/App.jsx. What should I do? Any ideas to how to implement this logic and make the app remove only the checked ones from the mongo collection?

Here is the code I have so far. It is equal to the code on the 7th step of the tutorial. The only differences are my comments (lots of them) and the function I am trying to create.

http://pastebin.com/SJCTjJNK - Bad formatting when I was trying to paste the code here.

Thanks, in advance.

Comment: Post the code you have so far

Comment: @NicolaPedretti, Sure thing. Updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting error because you are not passing the Id in remove function.

So the correct syntax will be :

```
Collection.remove(id);
```

You can write a function, which only checked todo item will be deleted:

```
Meteor.methods({
  'tasks.removeChecked'() {
      Collection.remove({ checked: true });
  }
});
```

Comment: Yes. This part I understand. But how do I get the id of a single task from the main App itself? I managed to get an array of the tasks using 'this.props.tasks;' but then, I can't get the ID from the objects in the array.

Comment: You can manage the IDs from the checkbox when the user checked on the checkbox you can push the current doc id into the ids array if user unchecked remove the id from the ids array.